# Lucene blocks while searching and indexing at the same time

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, lucene

I have a java application that uses Lucene (latest version, 5.2.1 as of this writing) in "near realtime" mode; it has one network connection to receive requests to index documents, and another connection for search requests.

I'm testing with a corpus of pretty large documents (several megabytes of plain text) and several versions of each field with different analyzers. One of them being a phonetic analyzer with the Beider-Morse filter, the indexing of some documents can take quite a bit of time (over a minute in some cases). Most of this time is spent in the call to IndexWriter.addDocument(doc);

My problem is that while a document is being indexed, searches get blocked, and they aren't processed until the indexing operation finishes. Having the search blocked for more than a couple seconds is unacceptable.

Before each search, I do the following:

```
DirectoryReader newReader = DirectoryReader.openIfChanged(reader, writer, false);

if (newReader != null)
{
    reader = newReader;
    searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
}
```

I guess this is what causes the problem. However, is the only way to get the most recent changes when I do a search. I'd like to maintain this behaviour in general, but if the search would block I wouldn't mind to use a slightly old version of the index.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Among other options, consider having always an `IndexWriter` open and perform "commits" to it as you need.

Then you should ask for index readers to it (not to the directory) and refresh them as needed. Or simply use a [`SearcherManager`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_2_1/core/index.html?org/apache/lucene/search/SearcherManager.html) that will not only refresh searchers for you, but also will maintain a pool of readers and will manage references to them, in order to avoid reopening if the index contents haven't change.

See more [here](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/09/lucenes-searchermanager-simplifies.html).

Comment: I'm not sure this has much to do with my question. I already had an IndexWriter always open. The problem was when I tried to update the near-realtime IndexSearcher; if IndexWriter was writing, it waits until the indexing operation is complete, and some of my documents take really long to index (over a minute). I fear SearcherManager won't  help at all, but thanks for the link; i didn't knew about it.